# Sitecore - Adding custom fields to the User editor

Tags: c#, .net, sitecore

Is it possible to add custom fields on some tab of the User editor to for example allow Sitecore users to have a profile image?
We want a Sitecore based website to allow certain people to visit pages which other user types can't see. Also we want a list of all users with a certain profile. This made me think of custom user fields in the editor, but is this even possible, or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should read the entire section "User Profiles" in [Security API Cookbook](https://doc.sitecore.com/legacy-docs/SC70/security-api-cookbook-sc60-and-later-a4.pdf). Especially, the paragraphs " How to Extend the Default User Profile" and "Implement a Custom User Profile" should answer the question you ask.